# How can I design DB system while I want to change the ownership of records to the others when record is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming I have these 4 models.
Then I'm using the gem called `acts_as_paranoid` for each model to implement logical deletion.

- User
- Community
- Topic
- Comment

User can resign anytime he wants. It means User's record will be deleted.
In general situation, communities, topics, and comments that are created by the user, should be also deleted together.  (w/ dependant => destroy )

However, I don't want that. Because the other User might have added the community to his bookmark list. So for this reason they shouldn't be deleted.

When supposing that the user record was deleted but all those communities, topics and comments were remained, it starts returning nil error at the community page or wherever  which was made by the user.

I'm coding like just this now.
It's gonna be nil everywhere since the user record is gone but all the records remain.
How can I handle this kind of problem?

**views/communities/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @community.user.username %>
```

What I want to do is, replacing the username displayed with this fixed word "Not Found User".  Then possibly I'd just change the ownership(user_id) of community to the other User so that he can manage this community instead.

My association is just like this.

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :communities
has_many :topics
has_many :comments
```

**models/community.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :topics
has_many :comments
```

**models/topic.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
has_many :comments
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :community
belongs_to :topic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to refrain from deleting but put code in your display logic to handle a user that has been deleted. If you stick with acts_as_paranoid this would work fine, what I would do is use a helper method for username such as:

```
def community_username(community)
  user = User.with_deleted.find(community.user_id)
  if user.deleted_at.blank?
    return user.username
  end
  "[deleted]"
end
```

You can put this in your appropriate helper or application helper and call it in your view like

```
<%= community_username(@community) %>
```

and it will display their username, or [deleted] if it has been deleted.

Note the above code is off the top of my head, you may need to adjust slightly if I'm forgetting acts_as_paranoids methods...

Comment: Thanks for brilliant idea, this looks really cool! I have 2 questions. Is `with_deleted` ActiveRecord's method? I can use it without doing anything? If I'm adding your method `community_username`, should it be in application_helper.rb? or communities_helper?

Comment: with_deleted is part of acts_as_paranoid so if you are using that it should be fine (though check the docs to make sure I got that right). It's basically a scope it adds to search including deleted users (without it User.find will ignore any marked as deleted). You can add this wherever you like, but traditionally you would add it to communities_helper if it is only needed in the views related to the communities controller, or application_helper if you may need it everywhere.

Comment: and one more question:) If it's displaying over 100 users at one page loading, won't it be way slower to code like `<%= community_username(@community) %>` instead of `<%= @community.user.username %>` because it passes variable to your method every each line and calculate to return result?

Comment: It could be. There is not much overhead in passing the variable, but there is in lazy loading the user for each (one sql query per user per community). If you were listing 100 communities on a page like this you would want to fetch your communities and users in one query. You could add a new relation to your community model such as `has_many :users_with_deleted, :class_name => "User", :with_deleted => true`.

Comment: With this relation you could fetch your communities with `Community.includes(:users_with_deleted)` and when you pass to the helper, instead of fetching the user you could just access community.user. This way it would do one query for all rather than n+1 queries.

Comment: Thanks, Chad! if possible could you please put that in you Answer within block? It makes more understanding:)

Comment: `<%= link_to community_username(topic), show_user_path(topic.user) if topic.user %>` now I'm coding like this for every each line. If I take off `if topic.user`, obviously it returns 'nil' error because the user is deleted. Is this normal way to do? Do I add it for every single line??

Comment: I would handle the link_to in the helper. Update the helper so if the user is not deleted it would return the link_to and if the user is deleted it just returns a string. That way your view logic is simplified to just calling the helper and you have a single location where this logic resides.